# Como aumentar um input text e fazer quebra de linha automatica

Tags: php, input

Olá, como pode ver na imagem, o input esta maior que a parte que digito o texto e caso eu continue digitando ele não faz a quebra de linha, oque devo fazer ??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso é um input ou textarea? acho que queres usar `textarea` se queres quebra de linha...  O que vêz no CSS que possa estar a fazer isso?

Comment: È um input do tipo text.

Answer (score 5):

Você não pode. O único elemento HTML feito pra ter várias linhas é a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea):

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
```

A partir do HTML 5 você pode usar o atributo `wrap="hard"` pra forçar a quebra de linha automática.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.